# Self-promotion abuse detected?

Tags: discussion

There is an official FAQ on the issue: [Limits for self-promotion in answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers), BUT, it does not suggest what someone is to do when they find it, and where the line should be drawn.

I've found what I think is a clear case from the following users:

- https://stackoverflow.com/users/1174246/tonystark
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/1284828/justintoxicated
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/754215/henry

Each of these users has linked to "unlocktheinbox.com" in all or a majority of their answers. The last on the list has also posted a number of other low quality answers. From my perspective, it looks like a minimal effort to raise enough reputation to carry out promotional activities.

In an overwhelming majority of the answers, they have not received any upvotes, leading me to believe that they were not completely relevant or even helpful to the OP or subsequent visitors. That fact places these posts firmly in the "spam" category, but they **are** on-topic... ish.

My questions, then, are where is the line for when self-promotion is abusive, and what should a user do when they find this sort of thing? Flags?

Comment: As opposed to self-abuse promotion?

Comment: @bmargulies That is a totally different site, which is absolutely not in my recently-cleared browsing history.

Comment: It is obvious that the line must be drawn here. This far. No further.

Comment: Hmmm... I just came across and handled an interesting "other" flag entered a short while ago. ;)

Comment: Interesting. I had wondered the same thing with respect to [Nancy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1042733/nancy), whose answers are blatantly promotional, but relevant and [occasionally accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026161/c-sharp-word-document-fails-to-open/8102287#8102287). :-\

Comment: @Michael Flagged it :) And I found another with the same company: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1065282

Comment: Ha! Ha! It reminds me of me. Once I developed a free software which I linked to in an answer for promotion. I got a message from moderator and then again I never did that.

Comment: Hmm-mm ... Then I must confess I recently did the exact same thing as @VarunAgw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23050913/uncrush-png-image-on-ubuntu/23068738#23068738. What does "for promotion" entail, when it points to a free utility? IOW am I allowed to share the results of my personal discoveries/projects? I also regularly point people to my version of InDesign's JS reference.

Comment: @Jongware Well, I accepted Brad's answer, but truth be told, my question remains: where is the line? If you link to your own for-profit stuff in *every. single. answer*, then I think you've crossed the line. What about 50% of your answers? 25%? I don't know.

Comment: Ah, thanks--then I guess I'm still in the safe zone. I *do* have 1 single purely commercial product "out there" but if I find myself in a position to refer to it, I always (try to) disclose I'm the writer, it's commercial, and that there are other alternatives (free *or* paid). All of my other stuff is free.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

If you believe a user or group of users are spamming a product or site, I typically recommend using an "other" flag on one of their posts and explaining the situation in detail. For example:

> This user, along with userXXXX and userYYYY, appear to work for this company and are promoting their products across the site.

That's easy enough for us to look into, determine links between the users involved, and message or destroy accounts as necessary.

Comment: Possibly linking to some of their answers showing the abuse is helpful for mods also?

Comment: @codeMagic - If you flag one of the posts that has a specific URL, it's easy for us to do a `url:site.com` query and pull up the rest. I typically work through their post history anyway to see if this is truly a spammer or if they have other good posts to their name.

Comment: Ah, ok. Due diligence...I like it!