# Consensus on self-promotion and spam

Tags: discussion, support, spam, self-promotion

I just spotted a user with a lot of reputation with 273 answers, 138 of which contained a link to a website they're related to, and they often, but not always, contained disclosed affiliation. The most recent of these answers is from Apr 19<sup>th</sup>, and they date back to 2010.

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252812/5210517), we should flag for moderator attention (A.K.A. custom-flag, mod-flag) but I intend to make an exhaustive guideline for future reference, rather than just bringing the issue to the flags.

1. Is self-promotion different from spam? Do they get different treatments? If so, what are the differences between how spammers and self-promoters are handled?
2. How do each of the bullet points below affect how we judge whether something is spam, overt self-promotion or neither of those, if they have any effect?

   - the user having any other meaningful contributions
   - the promoted link answers the question
   - the question is a request for tools or libs
   - repetition of the link in other answers of the user
   - affiliation disclosed
   - the link being blatantly irrelevant
   - the date of the post, or its last activity

I believe self-promotion/spam, if proved, gets either of these four treatments, or a combination of those, from normal users:

- spam flags
- close the question
- flag answers as link-only (VLQ)
- edit the link out

Moderators might take further actions, like suspending repeat offenders for a long time.

Comment: Lot of good information here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion

Comment: *for a long time.* That is highly speculative and the angry mob here doesn't get to decide on suspension lengths. Stay close the facts please.

Comment: @rene I was thinking of the network-wide suspensions persistent trolls get. Of course people don't decide what the length of the suspensions is, but I'm expecting to hopefully get an official answer on this mods can put a link to in the future whenever it's needed in a relevant discussion, so about things that shouldn't be disclosed, a "we're gonna put 'em in timeout for a long long time" would suffice.

Comment: @M.A.R. You don't need to *care* how a mod is going to handle it.  They're going to handle it (and these things tend to be very context dependant anyway).  Everything that you need to know is covered in the help center article on the subject.  If you really want to see more discussion on the topic, there've been *lots* of meta discussions over the years on self-promotion, if you want to see various specific examples and what people have thought of them.

Comment: @Servy you say that, but there's still not enough consensus on grayer areas. For instance, today a user posted three answers linking to some website, and I reported them all to SmokeDetector because they didn't contain affiliation, the user had no other contributions and they were posted in a 15-minute window. One of those was under a tool request, and in a discussion with a mod, we should ideally not flag that as spam, but close the question instead. That's the reason I posted this meta post, because we don't agree on how they should be handled.

Comment: @M.A.R. For a lack of disclosure you shouldn't flag as spam, you should cast a custom mod flag so the moderator can look into it and handle the situation appropriately.  A lack of disclosure isn't something to kill the account over in most cases, it's something to have the author fix and get a warning to ensure it doesn't continue.

Comment: @Servy considering most blatant spam doesn't contain disclosed affiliation, deciding that in the edge cases gets hard. And that's part of what constitutes an answer.

Comment: @M.A.R. Are you seriously saying that you're unable to tell the difference between a post that's nothing but an advertisement and a post that's a good answer that just fails to disclose affiliation?  I don't see that as being particularly hard to distinguish; of course if you're really stuck on a post and are unsure, you can always sway on the site of a custom flag and let a moderator decide.

Comment: No, I don't have any problem distinguishing the two extremes of the spectrum, but there have been previously posts nuked that were NAA + link to website. Such posts were from OPs that didn't have any other activity for me to decide whether it's spam, or just simple NAA. Do I have to crack a walnut with a warhammer, or is this really not just a walnut?

Comment: @M.A.R. *Such posts were from OPs that didn't have any other activity for me to decide whether it's spam* - that you could see...

Comment: There is also tools like metasmoke that I can use to distinguish whether a website has spammed SE before @Servy, and there are quite some innocuous-looking posts that were deleted as spam or abusive, whose only way of being different from normal posts is that they fit the normal pattern of spam waves that hit SO, or have spammed here [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43338914/why-can-t-pic16f877a-delay-after-entering-interruption#comment73741283_43338914) (10k-only link).

Comment: @M.A.R. If you don't have enough evidence to determine if a post is spam then you *don't flag it as spam*.  You flag posts as spam when you can unambiguously see that it's spam.  If you'd like a mod to look into a user and see if they're posting spam or other inappropriate promotion, feel free to cast an appropriate flag.

Comment: Another related FAQ link for any reader who is unfamiliar: http://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support AKA "Can I support my product here"

Comment: There's questions of what to do when there's spam-like behavior that's on topic and potentially useful...so are we almost [here](https://xkcd.com/810/) then?

Answer (score 62):

First, it's useful to talk about why this community strongly dislikes undisclosed self-promotion. We hate off-topic commercial spam (weight loss pills, etc.) for obvious reasons, because it's pure trash that belongs nowhere. Undisclosed self-promotion of products that in some way target on-topic questions are more of a problem because they are untrustworthy. The author of a commercial product is clearly biased, and anyone reading their answer deserves to know this and take it into account.

The above forms the basis of how we act on self-promotion, along with judgments about intent. There have been [significant debates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86717/defining-the-limits-of-self-promotion) about [how much self-promotion is too much](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers), even when proper disclosure is provided. If someone's sole intent is to promote their product or project, even proper disclosure may not protect their answers. However, [there are ways that people can mention their own work without it becoming a problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182212/what-signifies-good-self-promotion-or-self-promotion-part-infinity).

With that in mind, I can address how I approach people who have been flagged for spam or self-promotion. I do split these into two groups, based on whether I think there is any chance they can change their behavior.

The factors you list above play into this: do they have any other non-promotional contributions, is this a commercial product they're promoting, is the product anywhere near relevant, and so on. Someone advertising weight loss pills or rock crushing equipment isn't worth any more thought, destroy the posts, destroy the accounts, see if there are any others spamming from that location, and move on. Nothing we say will change them in the least.

On the other side are people promoting open source libraries that do target the question asked. [I've talked about this in detail](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229091/135615), but I have an open source library I actually built to address common questions I saw being asked here. As a result, I'm sympathetic towards people who have built something they're proud of but who are maybe a little overzealous in their advocacy of it. I tend to reach out to people like that and try to nudge them in the right direction (proper disclosure, more detail in answers than just a link, specifically answering the question asked, etc.). Destruction of posts and accounts for this is pretty rare.

Then there are the people in between those two. Someone providing undisclosed self-promotional content for a commercial product that does address a specific question tends to be handled more often like a true spammer. This is where we take a hard look at their other contributions. Are their only posts on the site ones that promote a product? Do they speak in glowing advertising copy about the wonders of this product? Do they intentionally hide their affiliation with the product or masquerade as a third party? That's likely to result in post and account destruction, because they know what they're doing.

If there's any chance at all that I think someone could listen to reason and stop the self-promotion and stick to more productive contributions, I'll warn first and probably delete the offending posts. If someone has been warned and they continue to self-promote in an unacceptable manner, they shouldn't be surprised to find their account suspended or removed.

Moderators have a lot of context that normal members don't, so I recognize that it can be harder to judge whether something should be flagged and how. In general, be wary of new users posting glowing recommendations for commercial products to old questions. If someone is only posting links to a product, blog, or YouTube channel, and nothing else, that's probably bad. If a member with 5000 reputation who has been around for three years posts a couple of links to a commercial product, they're probably not a spammer.

If in doubt, custom flags that explain the details of an odd situation are generally appreciated. Even if you're wrong, I try to mark these as helpful when I see them.

Comment: As a geologist I think rock crushing equipment highly useful!

Comment: That is a thorough and helpful answer.

Comment: Promoting your library in an answer about self-promotion. Flagged.

Comment: Reminds me of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293459/1188513)

Answer (score 13):

> Is self-promotion different from spam? Do they get different treatments? If so, what are the differences between how spammers and self-promoters are handled?

## Yes

**Spam** is handled with spam flags, that if validated destroys the post, bring -100 rep to user and the spammer account is often deleted as well. Furthermore it may bring an IP ban to the IP used by spammer (which can block more the one user). We should really avoid this if we are not sure it is an actual spamming attempt.

**Self-promoters** are handled by custom moderator flags, moderators will decide on an action based on additional information they have given their privilege. The action they may take can vary from just informing the user to applying spam flag (hence destroy post and the user).

Before addressing your different points, I will give you my points what I look for before red flagging an answer as spam.

### My checklist before flagging spam; all conditions must be met.

- Answer is irrelevant to the question or has copied another post to be able to add spam link.
- The link is direct to something that you gain profit of (blog with ads, products etc), not a Github link.
- The user has no other meaningful content.

If these points are not fulfilled, maybe it's just a new user very happy with his latest project that solves also an SO question and I look for the alternatives, that are:

1. Moderator flag the answer if you think it is better that people who have significant more information then you should have a look at the user.
2. VLQ flag the answer if it only contains a link
3. `>125` reputation Down vote answer
4. `>3K` reputation Close question (if asking for off-site resources)
5. `>10K` Delete vote the whole question (if not useful for SO, just a set of links)
6. `>20K` Delete vote the answer if it does not seem useful.

### Your bullet points

> - the user having any other meaningful contributions

Very low probability that you should spam flag, the best action in 99.9 (if not 100%) is to raise a moderator flag and let them handle the issue.

> - the promoted link answers the question
> - the question is a request for tools or libs

If the link answers the question, it is not spam anymore since it's not *["unsolicited"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spamming)*. However normally the question in these case should be closed and maybe also deleted. If you think the whole Q/A is just a spam setup (hence the question was only asked to be able to post a spam answer) raise a custom moderator flag.

> - repetition of the link in other answers of the user

An indicator of overt-self promotion, it does not necessary increase the probability of spam, since whether the post is spam or not you should judge from it's context.

> - affiliation disclosed

Is just a necessary attribute when you post information about your own products/libs etc. Note under certain circumstances it is not needed for example Bruno Lowagie does not need state in every answer he has under the [itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itext) that he is CTO at iText Group, it is enough that he has this information in his profile. If correct affiliation is not disclosed consider to add a comment under the post asking for this.

> - the link being blatantly irrelevant

Increase probability that you are looking at a spam post.

> - the date of the post, or its last activity

Probably it's less likely that a fresh post is hit by a spam answer, but I do not have statistics on this. I do not consider that when evaluating a post.

Comment: Undisclosed self-promotion _is_ spam. Read [Promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). Specifically, "However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers."

Comment: @QPaysTaxes but that's a [catch 22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22_(logic)) hence if not disclosed, how do you know it is to disclose?. So the issue becomes, not correctly disclosed, where actions can be all from comment to help user, moderator flag answer etc. all depending on what type of question and answer it is.

Comment: Say I write a blog on AngularJS and that blog does not contain ads, or other paid product-links. If I come across SO at some point, I'll start to link to my blog, obviously. Even if I write a proper answer containing all information and reference the link, will it be spam if I do that on all my answers? I vaguely remember a lad (I think in python) who posted lots of answers with purely a link to their non-commercial blog saying "that's easier to maintain for me than hundreds of separate SO answers".

Comment: @Adriaan 1. If link only, it's VLQ and should be deleted (the answer needs to work without the blog post), 2. If you pass identical answer on multiple questions, it should be deleted, since you should close vote as duplicate (hence comment). But if you answer an on-topic question adding a link to a blog post **(for additional info)** and if it is yours also provide disclosure, you are ok. [To external blog](http://stackoverflow.com/a/353241/5292302), [Personal blog](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8472470/5292302)

Comment: @PetterFriberg If this post contained a link to PetterFriberg.org, or to the website for Foo Bar Magazine and your profile said you were an editor there, or any number of other things that make it clear there's an affiliation without explicit disclosure in the post itself.

Comment: Exactly so it's not correctly disclosed according to SO policy (hence it's not really undisclosed) a new user may be in good faith and provide a good answer, link to his blog, where the link and name is the same as user profile. Do we like to spam flag that?, no we like to help'em out!. A stupid spammer can use the same name in user profile, so it gets easier for us to understand that it is spam. Conclusion the content of the question and the answer makes the difference, incorrect disclosure is **not** an automatic spam flag according to me.

Comment: @Petter a few years ago in another community, I met this one guy who was pretty adamant about making sure the people he was collaborating with knew his legal name, but didn't explain why. I didn't think much of it (thought it was a quirk or just weird). It turns out that if I had pasted the name into Google, I would have found out about some of the bad stuff he had done in the 1990's and the fairly long prison sentence he had gotten for it. He apparently thought that counted as "disclosing" his past to people. Fortunately, he seemed to have reformed and he was (and is) a great contributor.