# LAQ Spam or just VLQ?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts, spam, late-answers

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/18594828) in the Late Answer queue (image included below since I assume it will be nuked shortly)

[image]

which I down voted and flagged as VLQ.

Should I have flagged this as spam?

My doubts are that there is an implied affiliation by the author of the post, and that it appears to be a new user trying to help rather than deliberate spamming.

Comment: IMO it's not an answer, as it's (essentially) a link-only answer. I would say it's neither spam _nor_ VLQ.

Comment: This seems suspicious. That's the CTO of YugaByte posting an answer suggesting YugaByte. They posted another similar answer (with lots of links to their website) around the same time. I'm not sure it complies fully with [How not to be a spammer](/help/promotion).  Sometimes when I'm not sure about a post like this, I'll ask on the [SOCVR chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), to avoid the Meta Monster Smashing An Innocent Post.

Comment: I think none of the current flags are a good fit for this case and instead we need a new flag option: **posted as answer to a question that’s primarily opinion-based** — and the associated longer message should be, *“Answers should not be posted for a question that is primarily opinion-based. Instead the question should be flagged as being primarily opinion-based so it can be closed”…*

Comment: I'm not sure if the poster is an actual spammer or just abusing answers to promote their product. At any rate they need to stop doing that, so I have flagged the other non-deleted post by the same user for diamond mod attention.

Answer (score 21):

I wonder if the root problem isn’t actually with [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46106991/redis-for-caching-cassandra-rows/48391976#48391976) itself, which is *“Is it good to use Redis cache on the top of Cassandra?”*. Seems like the kind of question that gives lots of opportunities for a variety of bad answers. So to prevent even more bad answers getting posted to in the future, maybe the question itself should be closed as **primarily opinion-based**…

Comment: I agree, and have cast my vote on that question (but this does not really answer my question :)

Comment: @TravisJ, I know its a bad answer, which is why I flagged it - but the question was what flag should be used. And I agree getting rid of the question is best (and its now been deleted), but so many close actions just age away

Answer (score 13):

"Spam" is widespread, indiscriminate advertising. We've all seen real spam on SO; it tends to advertise handbags or herbal supplements, it usually doesn't even pretend to be on-topic, and it's gone after about 45 seconds.

The answer there is potentially *excessively self-promotional*, and if part of a larger pattern it should definitely be discouraged, but it's not the sort of thing we should pull out the nuclear-level anti-spam response for.

Comment: Note that "excessively self-promotional" is part of the guidelines for spam.  That said, you're right that it's usually best to use a custom mod flag, rather than a spam flag, but it *is* spam, just a type of spam best handled by a moderator.

Comment: At first glance I agree that it isn't at the anti-spam level for taking action. However, as Servy notes here, if you review the spam guidelines, https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion, this answer ticks almost every "don't do this" box for avoiding a spam flag. It *is* spam according to those guidelines.

Comment: @TravisJ That page is entitled "How not to be a spammer", and the activities it describes are not by themselves sufficient for something to be spam. The page is rather describing how to put yourself above suspicion.

Comment: I disagree. Your first sentence contradicts itself. There is the help page guidelines on how to not spam, and if your actions are in direct violation of those guidelines, then such actions "*will nearly always result in your posts being flagged as spam*". As such, the page is describing how to not be a spammer, which it is aptly titled. Once you have been labelled a spammer, then moderation will step in to see what type of steps need to be taken. You can see a good moderation response to how spam is handled from Bard Larson: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348498/1026459.

Comment: *"We've all seen real spam on SO"* - nope, it's probably so well handled, I've never yet seen anything, what I would call "a spam" here. To me "real spam" is goldsellers spam in public chat channels in MMOs (can be ridiculously annoying, making public channels unusable).

Answer (score 1):

By our definition of spam ("Exists only to promote a product or service, **does not disclose the author's affiliation**"), I would say this 'answer' does not fall into this category so I wouldn't give it a spam flag as the author of the answer states that they own it.

Regardless its not something that provides any use being posted as an answer so I would have flagged it as Not An Answer.