# Is this spam or self-promotion or different?

Tags: discussion, spam, self-promotion

After skipping [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/19129088) and [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/19128886) I took another look and saw this answer has been posted multiple times in the last hour by the same user. I'm starting to have some doubts about what to do here.

Should I flag these answers/user (and how) or are these answer fine?

Comment: To flag something like this, raise a custom moderator flag on any of these posts and fully explain the situation.

Comment: Between the excessive self-promotion, the copied text between answers, and the unnecessary promotional language, I think that this user is very much flaggable.

Comment: It is project spam.  The reviewers did not do a good job of it.  Moderators normally get an alert for repeated posts like this but that is temporarily bogged down and might not have worked due to the minor tweak in the first sentence.  Using a spam flag is surely best, they are handled with priority.

Comment: @HansPassant In that case should i flag all answers or just one?

Comment: Not actually sure if they look deeper to discover the other ones.  Flag 'em all, only way to be sure.

Comment: I just flagged the answers that were left as spam.

Comment: For spam, you can visit [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) to get a second opinion, or to get a lot of spam flags and be able to close it even faster than a mod would (though they tend to be fast with spam flags)

Comment: Since Alamofire is an OS project and the poster isn't a lead on it, I'd say that this is just a slight case of fanboyism.

Comment: A bit of duplicate-ception going on there @gnat. Unfortunatly I'm not able to see the reviews in this post anymore so I can't really say that duplicate is correct for this question.

Comment: I think I clicked duplicate a bit too fast here because later I found an even better / canonical duplicate target which has a [very thorough detailed answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348499/839601) intending to cover all possible cases of users promoting links to their site in all of their answers

Comment: Thanks for that link @gnat. That looks like a very good answer.