# What made this a low quality answer?

Tags: support, review-audits, low-quality-posts

I am still relatively new to Low Quality Post reviews, and I got hit on [this audit question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21503237), but I don't understand why.

I am definitely not familiar with google-bigquery, but this answer appeared to directly address the question and provided a screenshot to illustrate what they were talking about.

When I was reviewing, I saw that the question was asked 18 days ago with no other answers, so it didn't seem like a piggy backing post. I don't find it to be a particularly brilliant answer, but it looked like a legitimate attempt that would at least point someone in a new direction to help solve their problem, and it didn't seem to meet these guidelines:

> It is abusive nonsense, noise, spam, blatantly off-topic or otherwise irredeemable – readers will find it offensive or repulsive rather than helpful.

I want to make sure I'm not doing bad reviews. What am I missing here?

Comment: _"This answer was marked as **spam** or rude or abusive"_

Comment: It was spam for a product that had nothing to do with the question.  A basic way to pass these kind of audits, even without checking the validity of the answer, is to slow down a bit before you are going to dismiss a flag from a concerned SO user.  At a minimum have a look at the Q+A to see what other posts are there.  Not there anymore, you can't fail the audit.

Comment: I looked up that tool the answerer mentioned, and it's a free extension, so I'm not sure how exactly it is spam for commercial gain. If the answer didn't actually solve the problem, shouldn't that be handled with downvotes instead of flags?

Comment: Brad Larson deleted it, maybe he can explain?

Comment: Spam doesn't have to mean that the product costs money, I could spam by linking people to my personal blog since that would drive up page views and potentially net me some more ad money without the user spending anything. The point is, the link to the product was unsolicited and was advertising the product, even if it was free. If it had come with a good explanation as to why that tool actually does help solve the issue, then it might not have been spam, but in this case, the product suggestion was completely incorrect and not desired, just serving to promote the product.

Comment: There's a help center [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) that might give you insight in the meaning of "spam" in SE context.

Comment: In addition, the [user's profile](//stackoverflow.com/users/9376376/tamir-klein) indicates affiliation with web.superquery.io, which indicates they provide superQuery, the product that was promoted in the answer you were reviewing. The OP did not disclose *in the post* their affiliation with the product that they mentioned. That, by itself, makes the answer spam, under the definitions that SE/SO uses for spam. If it was a good answer, then it's reasonable to leave a comment asking the user to provide disclosure, but this is not a good answer, so it's spam. If you want to be nice, then NAA.

Comment: For more information about spam and self-promotion on SO see: [**What signifies "Good" self promotion?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212), [some tips and advice about self-promotion (How to not be a spammer)](/help/promotion), [What is the exact definition of "spam" for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638), [What makes something spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035), [Consensus on self-promotion and spam](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348489/3773011), and [Limits for self-promotion in answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57497/271271).

Comment: "I am definitely not familiar with google-bigquery" -- I think in cases like that picking Looks OK is borderline abuse. [There is no shame in using “Skip”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/839601)

Answer (score -8):

It's a one sentence answer with an image, and it does not stand without the image.

I don't like it. I can't quite understand it either. Also, this is a programming question. Where is the code in the answer.

For that matter, where is the code in the question? It's rather bad quality and I went back and downvoted it.